# see about this infix to postfix conversion

Tags: c

If we solve an infix expression in to postfix expression with braces and without braces will both of them produce same result?

**Example:**

1. ((2+8)x9)-(5x(5+2))
2. 2+8*9-5*5+2

Will both of these examples produce the same results? If No, then why not?

Comment: They will not produce the same result. Please go through this link. It will surely help:- http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/fix.html

Comment: In example 1 you are missing some operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it will not produce the same result, due to the precedence of the operations. For example, if you define `*` to have higher precedence than `+` and `-`, then `*` must be evaluated before `+` or `-`, which changes how the expression is calculated, and also changes the post-fix representation.